# Find functions $f$ for $|f(z)| \ge \frac{1}{|z|^n}$ for all $|z| \ge R$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently solving this problem but I'm stuck.

> Find all the functions analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ such that for fixed
>   $M, R\gt 0$ and fixed $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $|f(z)| \ge \frac{M}{|z|^n}$
>   for all $|z| \ge R$.

$$$$
Here, I was trying to use extended Liouville's theorem on $f$ but it just says about functions that are bounded "above" not "below". So I'm having trouble applying it here. I also tried searching for other problems for finding entire functions on given conditions to get some hint in approaching such problem but there seemed no particular hint for my specific problem.
$$$$Can you guys help me figure out this problem, or at least could you give me some guidance on how to think this in order to get to the answer? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the region $|z|\ge R$, $f(z)$ cannot have zeros. As it is an entire function,
it can only have a finite number of zeros in $|z|\le R$ (if the zeros are infinite in this region, by compactness there must be a cluster point, and the identity principle implies $f=0$, which is absurd). Now, inverting the inequality we obtain that $$\frac{1}{|f|}\le \frac{|z|^n}{M}$$ Thus $\frac{1}{f}$ is a function with
 a finite number of poles, that grows like a polynomial. We shall prove that the only meromorphic functions satisfying this requirements are the rational functions.

To prove it, consider the function $g(z):=\frac{\prod (z-z_i)^{m_i}}{f(z)}$, where $z_i$ are the 
poles of $\frac{1}{f}$, and $m_i$ the multiplicities. This function is analytically extendable to the whole plane (and thus it is entire) and grows like a polinomial of degree
$N:=\sum m_i +n$. Applying Cauchy inequalities (or directly Liouville generalized theorem if one wishes) we get

$$|a_k|\le r^{-k}\sup_{|z|=r}|f|\\
\forall k>N\ \ \ |a_k|\le \lim_{r\to \infty} r^{-k} Kr^N\to 0$$

Thus $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $N$. $\frac{1}{f}$ is then a rational function, and we obtain that $f$ is a rational function $\frac {P}{Q}$, with $\deg{Q}\ge \deg{P}+n$

As asked in the comments, here is a proof that an infinite set $T$ contained in $c_r$ must have a cluster point:
given $1>\varepsilon>0$, we can write $c_r$ as the finite union of (closed) balls of radius $\varepsilon$. Since the set $T$ is infinite, at least one of these balls $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ will contain infinite points of $T$. We can reitherate the process, writing the closed ball $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ as a finite union of balls of radius $\varepsilon^2$ and so one. Let $B_i$ be the ball chosen at the $i-$th step, and let $z$ be the only point contained in $\cap B_i$ (it is the only one since the diameter of this intersection is $0$, and it exists by topological completeness of $\mathbb{C}$). $z$ is, by construction, a cluster point of $T$.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why compactness of some set implies that infinite subset of it must have cluster point?

Comment: @pratjohn a set such that every sequence admits a convergent subsequence is called sequentially compact. For metric spaces, this is equivalent to usual compactness. Given an infinite set we can always find a sequence in it. Thus if a set is sequentially compact every infinite subset of it will have a cluster point

Comment: is there other explanation that can be shown directly from definition of compact set? Because im not familiar with sequential compactness and therefore "Given an infinite set we can always find a sequence in it" doesn't make much sence to me. It would be really helpful if you could explain it using definitions or some of elemental things to yield that infinite subset of infinite number of isolated point would be absurd, if possible. I came up with the idea which goes like, if there really are, then the minimum radius of neighborhoods would be nonzero. So total area would exceed

Comment: But im not sure if it's rigid

Comment: this depends on how much background you have: all of the proofs will inevitably have to use the topological completeness of $\mathbb{C}$ at some point (for example, the proof I have added to my answer needs it when I say that the intersection of nested closed balls is not empty)